# Handling Spring Batch flow job

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

**Situation :**

There is a batch steps named `A, B, C, D, E`.

A is always executed first.

Depending on A's exitStatus, if A gives "SOMECONDITION", B is executed. On "OTHERCONDITION" C is executed. Job instances are not allowed to execute both B and C.

Regardless of executed Step is B or C, they should go to D.

After executing D, by using `next()`, E is executed.

**Problem : Ugly code structure.**

By redundant use of `on(), to()`, I managed to figure out the flow that I need.

[image: Figure 1. Ugly nexts on each on-to conditionals]

As directly observable, there is really ugly code `next()` on each on-to, to direct them into common flow.

Adding more ugliness, I have to use `from()-on("*")` to direct each of on-to-next to some common flow.

**Question :**

At least this works, but i wonder, is this the only code that satisfies above condition?

Comment: I think the issue here is trying to define the complete flow inline in a single bloc. I added an answer where I show how to split the flow definition and compose basic flows to define the global one. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Problem : Ugly code structure.

> Adding more ugliness, I have to [...]

We, the Spring team, are always open to constructive feedback. So if you have ideas on how to improve the DSL of defining job flows, you are welcome to open a ticket on our issue tracker and we will do our best to improve things if needed.

Now to answer your question, the `next(...)` statements after each `on("..").to("..")` are not necessary. This is not what the documentation says, see example here: [Conditional Flow](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#conditionalFlow).

According to your description, the flow to implement is the following:

[image: flow]

This is actually a conditional flow (A -> decider -> B or C) followed by a sequential flow (D -> E).

The way I would define such flow is something like:

```
@Bean
public Job job() {
    Flow conditionalFlow = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("conditionalFlow")
            .start(stepA())
            .next(decider()).on("SOMECONDITION").to(stepB())
            .from(decider()).on("OTHERCONDITION").to(stepC())
            .end();


    return new JobBuilder("myJob", jobRepository)
            .start(conditionalFlow)
            .next(stepD())
            .next(stepE())
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

This way, the flows are clearly defined. Here is a complete sample that you can run and check the results (make sure to use Spring Batch 5 and to have HSQLDB in the classpath):

```
package org.springframework.batch.sample;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.FlowBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.Flow;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobExecutionDecider;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfiguration {

    private final JobRepository jobRepository;
    private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    public MyJobConfiguration(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        this.jobRepository = jobRepository;
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }

    private Step createStep(String stepName) {
        return new StepBuilder("step" + stepName, jobRepository)
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("running step " + stepName);
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                }, transactionManager)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepA() {
        return createStep("A");
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepB() {
        return createStep("B");
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepC() {
        return createStep("C");
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepD() {
        return createStep("D");
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepE() {
        return createStep("E");
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExecutionDecider decider() {
        return (jobExecution, stepExecution) -> {
            return new FlowExecutionStatus("SOMECONDITION"); // SOMECONDITION, OTHERCONDITION
        };
    }

@Bean
public Job job() {
    Flow conditionalFlow = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("conditionalFlow")
            .start(stepA())
            .next(decider()).on("SOMECONDITION").to(stepB())
            .from(decider()).on("OTHERCONDITION").to(stepC())
            .end();


    return new JobBuilder("myJob", jobRepository)
            .start(conditionalFlow)
            .next(stepD())
            .next(stepE())
            .end()
            .build();
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJobConfiguration.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }


    // infrastructure beans

    static class DataSourceConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                    .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                    .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql")
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
            return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
        }
    }

}
```

This sample prints:

```
running step A
running step B
running step D
running step E
```

If you make the decider return "OTHERCONDITION", the sample prints:

```
running step A
running step C
running step D
running step E
```

which is what is required from your description.

Comment: Okkay. So the main problem in my thought came from trying to make all the sequential and conditonal flows into just one Job. Thanks for your clear solution to divide them into each.
Forgive me, there was a reason - I was trying to use Composed Task Runner, which is type of spring batch, in Spring CDF to provide conditional execution by exitStatus. Since defining the task DSL graph seems to be defining one flowJob for CTR, I was trying to find any way to make flow in just one block. Anyway, your solution gives me insight of how to build flows in normal batch projects. Helped me a lot. Thanks!